# edit css style of an element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to edit the style of an element but do get an error. This is the code I tried:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Edge("edge.exe")

url = "my website url"
page = driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("document.getElementByName('h-captcha-response').style.display = 'block';") #want to change display: 'none' to display: 'block'
```

I do get an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: document.getElementByName is not a function
```

[image: screenshot of css I want to edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not '`document.getElementByName('h-captcha-response')`'

It is `'document.getElementsByName('h-captcha-response')'` with 's'.